# "name 'self' is not defined"

Tags: python

I'm reading the book "Make Your Own Neural Network" by Tariq Rashid.

This is my code:

import numpy

```
class neuralNetwork:

    def _init_(self,inputnodes,hiddennodes,outputnodes,learningrate): 
        self.inodes=inputnodes  
        self.hnodes=hiddennodes
        self.onodes=outputnodes

        self.lr=learningrate
        pass

    def train():
        pass

    def query():
        pass

self.wih=(numpy.random.rand(self.hnodes,self.inodes)-0.5)
self.who=(numpy.random.rand(self.onodes,self.hnodes)-0.5)
```

It produces this error:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd rather start with a basic tutorial on `Python`, then with the most advanced subjects... As for your error: you need to `import numpy` before, `numpy` is a famous library for all kinds of mathematical stuff.

Comment: You have to import it using `import numpy`  but I will agree with @Jan.

Comment: Did you `import numpy`? Your question title is a different error to the one in your question.

Comment: You haven't defined a class, and the constructor (init) requires double underscores (`def __init__()`).

Comment: Actually, I see you did define a class but your editing is off and it's not formatted as code. I can't currently fix it as I'm not at a PC, please fix. There is still a mismatch between your question title and the `NameError` in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first install the package with the command :

```
pip3 install numpy
```

on your shell (I assume you use Python 3).

After you need to write on the top your code :

```
import numpy
```

EDIT : With a quick search on Google, I found this :

```
class neuralNetwork:

    # initialise the neural network:
    def __init__(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate):
        #set number of nodes in each input, hidden, output layer:
        self.inodes = inputnodes #why can't we immediately use the inputnodes?
        self.hnodes = hiddennodes
        self.onodes = outputnodes

        #Setting the weights:
        self.wih = np.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.hnodes, -0.5),(self.hnodes,self.inodes))
        self.who = np.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.onodes, -0.5),(self.onodes, self.hnodes))    

        #learning rate:
        self.lr = learningrate

        #activation function:
        self.activation_function = lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x) 

        pass
```

You should check Python tutorials first and be careful with indentation.

Comment: I both installed and imported numpy, but It shows me "NameError: name 'self' is not defined."